# Can i implement a stretchy image header in UIScrollView (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I already learned how to create a stretchy header in `UICollectionView` but in real life i often use a `UIScrollView`. I try to implement it but it isn't work.

```
let originHeight = imageHeightConstraint.constant
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let contentOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if contentOffsetY < 0 {
            self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = originHeight + abs(contentOffsetY)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Ps - sorry for bad grammar, I am not good at English.

Comment: update your view after changing imageViewContraint height self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 2):

Everything is good, you just need to add layoutIfNeeded after you update your constraint.

```
 let originHeight = imageHeightConstraint.constant
        extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
            func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
                let contentOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
                if contentOffsetY < 0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = originHeight + abs(contentOffsetY)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```